# How to turn sqlite lat/lon columns to spatialite geometry?

Tags: spatialite, sqlite

I have a sqlite database with a table that has a column for longitude and one for latitude. Is there a way to make this data base 'spatial'?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've described the process of installing and spatially enabling an sqlite db here: [SpatiaLite Quick Start](http://underdark.wordpress.com/2010/06/23/spatialite-quick-start/). Basically, you need to get init_spatialite-2.3.sql and run it on your db.

You can then create point geometries using this function:

```
MakePoint( x Double precision , y Double precision , [ , SRID Integer] ) : Geometry
```

Comment: thanks, that worked well in combination with Gene's suggestions.

Answer (score 9):

first, you need to enable spatialite in your sqlite database

```
sqlite> .load 'libspatialite.so,dll or dylib'
```

or

```
SELECT load_extension(libspatialite.so,dll ou dylib)
```

`

After that you need to initialize your database with init_spatialite-2.3.sql

```
sqlite> .read '~/init_spatialite-2.3.sql'
```

Comment: Note that the init_spatialite-2.3.sql step is not applicable for spatialite 3.0 or later.